# Error in Xamarin Android with a progress dialog “Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views”

Tags: xamarin.android, progressdialog

I'm trying to use a progress dialog, while filling a datagrid, but I get the following error: "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views", this is my code, i hope they can help me

```
public async void RelacionClientesREST()
        {
            try
            {
                var dlg = ProgressDialog.Show(this, "Loading", "Cargando relación de usuarios");
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(d => {

                    RestClient client = new RestClient("http://portalclientewa.azurewebsites.net/api/RelacionClientes/");
                    var request = new RestRequest("GetData", Method.GET);
                    request.Timeout = 1500000;
                    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
                    request.AddParameter("idP", Idp);
                    var temp = client.Execute(request).Content;
                    var parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(temp).ToString();
                    var lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ClientesProp>>(parsedJson).ToList();
                    dataGrid.ItemsSource = lst;

                    RunOnUiThread(() => {
                        dlg.Dismiss();
                    });
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "No hay datos registrados", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you the app's UI must be handled by the main thread. In your code, you are running some code on a background thread (ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem) that needs to be run on the UI thread (RunOnUiThread) instead.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use dlg.Dismiss(); inside ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem, move it before try close sign

Answer (score 1):

why not use Task instead?

```
Task.Run(() => doStuff("hello world"));
```

It doesn't really seem a lot better, but at least it doesn't have an unused identifier.

Note: Task.Run() is .Net 4.5 or later. If you're using .Net 4 you have to do:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff("hello world"));
```

Both of the above do use the thread pool.

Answer (score 1):

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

As @CaPorter said,  **the app's UI must be handled by the main thread**. [There are any number of ways to get code to execute on the UI thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/8289#Comment_8289), you could try using `Looper.MainLooper` with `Handler.Post()`.

Modify your code like this :

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(d => {

    ...

    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.MainLooper);
    Action action = () =>
    { 
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = lst;
        dlg.Dismiss();
    };
    handler.Post(action);
});
```